# Force Desktop CSS on Mobile Device with Pinch, Zoom & Scroll (Pan)

Tags: android, html, ios, css

So we're making our site mobile friendly but we're not even close to being done yet.  Our desktop version works well but has big tables (that we are getting rid of -- slowly).  In the meantime our mobile frame `<section>` cuts off our content.  We would like it to show everything and just allow the user to zoom and pinch and scroll on their device like other non-mobile friendly sites.  How do we do that?  We have tried `<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`
 with no luck.  Thank you!

Comment: Part of what I believe is the problem is our outer `<section>` has a 100% width.  Which is mostly fine, but on mobile the content is way bigger than the `device-width` so I am _thinking_ there is an `overflow:hidden` somewhere but not able to find it.  Even `overflow:scroll !important` does not work to show the content; it is still cut off.

Comment: with the minimum-scale=1 and maximum-scale=1 they cant scale it at all

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use on almost all of my sites

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Edit:** changed width